# Ionic AngularJS access form from external button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my template I want to save a form from an external button.
My problem is : The button don't know **form_connect** form because it appears after the  tag.

There is my template :

```
<form name="form_connect">
    <input name="field" />
</form>
<ion-footer-bar align-title="left" class="bar-calm">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button ng-click="save(form_connect)" ng-show="form_connect.$valid">POST</button>
  </div>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

There is a way to do that ?

I can't put the button on the  because **ion-footer-bar** will not positionned at bottom if I do that.

I already tried to defined a **$scope.form_connect** var in order to get a global var but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are they in the same ```$scope```? Can you put them in the same scope? Wrap them in a parent div?

Comment: Yes I put them in the same $scope (so the same controler) and I can wrap them in a parent div.

Comment: Then there needs to be an ```ng-model``` on your ```input``` so that you can get it into your ```$scope``` object. ```$scope.form_connect``` isn't going to work because you are not telling Angular to the ```$scope``` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to access form through $scope object.

## First approach (doesn't work)

In my case, the following statement can't let me to access at form by  **form_connect**. :

```
$scope.form_connect;
```

## A working approach

But, we can define an **form_list** object on $scope :

```
$scope.form_list = {};
```

Define the form :

```
<form name="form_list.form_connect">
```

And the button can access to form :

```
<button ng-click="save(form_list.form_connect)" ng-show="form_list.form_connect.$valid">POST</button>
```

I hope it will helps you.